GitLab to Jira Integration: Transitions Not Working (Only "Close" Works)
I have successfully enabled GitLab to Jira integration. I'm able to comment Jira issue IDs in GitLab, and the link between GitLab and Jira gets created. However, transitions (e.g., "In Progress") are not working for me.
I haven't made any changes in Jira except for creating an API token. The only transition that works is "Closes MYPROJECT-5."
In GitLab settings under Settings > Integration > Transition Jira issues to their final state, I've enabled Jira transitions and selected "Use custom transitions." I have provided the following transition IDs:
11,21,31
11: To Do
21: In Progress
31: Done
Despite configuring this, transitions like "In Progress" aren't working. Do I need to configure anything else in Jira or GitLab to make these transitions work?
Any guidance would be appreciated!
